# WooCommerce: Add to cart shortcode style

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I implemented the add_to_cart shortcode of WooCommerce, but default style appears and I don't succeed to modify it.

Shortcode :
`[add_to_cart id="99"]`

Default style defined by woocommerce

```
array(
  'id' => '99',
  'style' => 'border:4px solid #ccc; padding: 12px;',
  'sku' => 'FOO')
```

How can I modify this default styles?

*(Modifying the main style.css doesn't work)*

[image: Screenshot of Shortcode [product id="99"] vs [add_to_cart id="99"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the styles in the shortcode...

```
[add_to_cart id="27" style="border-right:1px solid #ccc"]
```